# Python Error with iteration, for loop

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am having a problem with my iteration statement. I want to compare the letter x with the value inside to equal 12.

I wRIte in python

```
   list     =    9876554321
for        x = list:
 if result -> 12
output "Succes'
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound snarky, but: are you sure you're writing Python? Because if so you have syntax errors and/or indentation errors on every single one of your lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the formatting tips, it will help you display your code as you wish.

that said, I think this is what you want.

The following code will iterate through each character in your list string.
If it finds a match, it will print success

```
list = "9876554321"
for char in list:
    if char == "9":
        print("Success')
```

Comment: Thank you Matt_G, for being helpful, unlike kevin

Comment: @HelenMirren You are welcome. If I solved your question, please consider taking a moment and accepting my answer.